# NHibernate 2.1.2 throwing DateTime null overflow exception

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm having a similar problem to these questions:

[NHibernate 2.* mapping files: how to define nullable DateTime type (DateTime?)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593236/nhibernate-2-mapping-files-how-to-define-nullable-datetime-type-datetime)

[NHibernate won't persist DateTime SqlDateTime overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645399/nhibernate-wont-persist-datetime-sqldatetime-overflow)

I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2 and FluentNhibernate 1.0.0.636. With NHibernate 2.x the nullable `DateTime?` issue should be fixed and I shouldn't have to do anything special with my mapping. Accordingly, all my DateTime properties are simply set like so:

```
public virtual DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

In my database (SQL2008), all DateTime properties are set to allow null. I have my NHibernate config file setup to use the SQL2008 dialect:

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
```

NHibernate works fine for anything that does not include a DateTime. For reference, here's the exact error I'm receiving:

```
> at
> NHibernate.AdoNet.SqlClientSqlCommandSet.ExecuteNonQuery()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException:
> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between
> 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999
> 11:59:59 PM.
```

If I run SQL Profiler, I can see the last command that NHibernate attempts to execute (this was a very long statement, so I've truncated it):

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE Projects SET Job = @p0, CreatedOn = @p1, .. WHERE (Where Clause), @p0=219221, @p1=NULL
```

If I execute this statement as a query, SQL persists it fine, doesn't complain at all!

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but this works [here](http://statichippo.com/archive/2010/01/07/calendar-sizes-datetime-vs-nullable-sqldatetime-in-nhibernate.aspx). Unlike the example in the link, mine are `DateTime?` so .... I do not know why it works, but it does.

Comment: A DateTime? works because it allows the DateTime to be null.If a date-time is not-nullable (just DateTime), it gets instantiated to the min-value, which is 1/1/0001.

Answer (score 1):

Your DateTime properties are probably set to DateTime.MinValue (1/1/0001) instead of null or a value in the valid range for a DateTime column.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. At first I thought I fixed it by switching my sql type from a nullable date to a nullable datetime. However, that was a mirage. The root cause was a cascading update on another newly added table.

This would have been quickly resolved if everyone (but especially MS) threw more descriptive errors. Cest la vie.